# What is the difference between an Operator and Method?

Tags: java, operator-keyword

What is the difference in the evaluation rule of an operator and a method in Java?

Comment: Your question makes no sense in either C or Java.

Comment: There are quite a few languages which allow operator overloading (with a method or function or however you call it). Neither C nor Java are among them. C++ and Python for instance are.

Comment: @Greg: I just want to know how are operators and methods evaluated in Java.

Comment: Many operators can be mapped by the compiler to simple machine language operations, so the compiler does this directly. Methods, on the other hand, are usually compiled to a call to the machine language translation of your code for that method, unless the compiler has inlined the method.

Comment: @JamesKPolk But it make sense in c#.i read Illustrated CSharp 2012 and in chapter 8 writer say : "an operator is symbol that represents an opration that returns single result".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Femaref's answer is pretty good; I'd like to expand on it.

Operators are (usually) hard-wired into the language: Stuff like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` are usually directly translated by the compiler into machine language (if that's the underlying mechanism for that language system) without the need to explicitly call a method in a library. This is how it is/was in C, for instance. If those operators weren't defined in the language, you'd have to code `plus(2,2)` instead of `2 + 2`.

Operators defined in the language come with the benefit of built-in priority. `*` and `/` usually have higher priority than `+` and `-`, so you can write `3 * 3 + 4 * 4` and get 25, not 52 or 84 that you'd get without such priorization or different priorities.

The line becomes a little grey when operators are recognized by the compiler but still delegated to a library. Complex numbers in FORTRAN may be an example: Often the compiler will not bother to directly compile complex operations into machine code but will generate machine code to call a library.

Most people think only of the arithmetic operators, like `+`, `-` and so forth. But you could also consider square brackets ( `[ ]` ) an operator for array indexing, for example.

Some languages let you overload their operators, so you can substitute a call to a method for whatever the operator normally does.

Most languages don't let you define your own operators that support the same mechanisms as the built-in ones. Scala is an exception here; you can define a `+++` operator if you like and have it hook up to a method you provide. Some people think operator overloading makes code harder to understand, so the jury is still out about whether this is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Operators can be seen as syntactic sugar for

```
static Foo Plus (Foo right, Foo left)
 {
   // do stuff
   return output;
 }
```

It's just more convinient to write `right + left` instead of `Class.Plus(right, left)`.

Comment: Not at all, if you think in "+" as a method, to which class belongs? to Object like the "toString()" method?

Answer (score 0):

In both C and Java you cannot override '+' operator for your classes so your question makes sense for other languages.

There are languages where operators can be overriden such as C++ and Python. If you are interested in such comparison why not to try? Even of your tests shows that '+' operator is slower/faster than .add() method this can change if you change compiler or environment.

I think you should use something that looks good for you.

There was advices in Java to use `StringBuffer` instead of `+` operator with `String` but newest Java implementations make better optimalization for `+` operator, so this advice is not that good for new code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a different guess at what you're asking. You might be asking, for instance, what Java guarantees about the order in which `bar()` and `baz()` are executed in the following two cases:

```
foo.bar() + foo.baz()
fee(foo.bar(), foo.baz())
```

In both cases, `bar()` is definitely called before `baz()` (JLS 15.7.1,4)